# Gps distance between two points

Tags: gps

I am developing a Meter app (in android). I am calculating distance between two points by formula (in back ground)

```
double calculateDistancs(double lat1, double long1, double lat2,
        double long2) {
    double earthRadius = 6371000; // meters

    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(long2 - long1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
            + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
            * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLng / 2)
            * Math.sin(dLng / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);
    return dist;

}
```

I am not getting same and accurate distance between my home to metro station .
Provide other approach if available  in android.

So second option is use google api for getting rout distance bn two latlong but in this case it will hit api many times.I want t know which approach is best.

I am getting different latlong at same place, may some one please make me understand for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most probably is not caused by the function you posted.
Probably you are summing up jumping gps locations.
Just summing up the distance from one location to the other is not sufficient, especially at low speeds, like walking speed.

However there are weak points in the formula:

```
  float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);
```

You are always using double, and then downgrade to the lower precision float, but return the double. This is makes no sense.

Fix that with:

```
 double dist = earthRadius * c;
```

Comment: Thanks for help. May you please provide some approach for accomplishment of this task. Is  there another way for doing this.

Comment: It helps when you visualize the locations, eg. in a kml file, and then look which locations you would exlclude from a distance calculation, and develop your own filtering technic.